# Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '<'. Expected Boolean, received Text

Tags: excel-formula, salesforce, salesforce-communities, salesforce-chatter, formula-editor

Here, I'm creating a new formulae field(text) based on the checkboxes. My requirement is if Attended, Canceled, Confirmed, Invited, Pending are unchecked show invited, if the confirmed checkbox is checked before the start date, The text to be populated as "confirmed". But, I'm getting error there. How can we compare those both. Any help

IF(AND(Attended__c ,Canceled__c ,Confirmed__c , Invited__c ,Pending__c),"False","Invited",
IF(OR(Confirmed__c,Confirmed__c<Start_Date_Time__c),"TRUE", "Confirmed",
IF((AND(Waiting_List__c,(!Confirmed__c)),"TRUE","Waitlisted","")))

Answer (score 0):

The `IF` function is not set up correctly as written. The set up for the function is `=IF(condition_is_met, value, value_if_not_met)`, so to have multiple `IF`'s nested together, you must set it up like so: `=IF(condition1_met, value, IF(condition2_met, value, value_if_condition2_not_met))`

Right now you have it set up like `=IF(condition1_met, value, value_if condition1_not_met, IF(condition2_met, value, value, value_if_condition2_not_met...`

Comment: Yes, After set up the "if condition true", The same error shown, I think it is expecting Boolean in place of date and time((Confirmed__c,Confirmed__c<Start_Date_Time__c)). How can I set up the condition for my requirement      
(Show confirmed in formulae field if the checkbox is checked before the start time-date)

Comment: Can you edit your question to add a screen shot of what the sheet currently looks like and what you want out of it? As is it is hard to understand what you are looking for